# Can Either be used for a kind of simple polymorphism?

Tags: haskell

I tried writing a simple function that takes an Either type (possibly parameterized by two different types) and does one thing if it gets Left and another thing if it gets Right.  the following code,

```
someFunc :: (Show a, Show b) => Either a b -> IO ()
someFunc (Left x) = print $ "Left " ++ show x
someFunc (Right x) = print $ "Right " ++ show x

main = do
  someFunc (Left "Test1")
  someFunc (Right "Test2")
```

However, this gives,

```
Ambiguous type variable `b0' in the constraint:
      (Show b0) arising from a use of `someFunc'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: someFunc (Left "Test1")
```

and

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `someFunc'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: someFunc (Right "Test2")
```

If I understand correctly, when I call the function with `Left x`, it is complaining because it doesn't know the type of the `Right x` variant, and vice-versa.  However, this branch of the function is not used.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that depends heavily on what you are trying to do, doesn't it? As you already found out, in order to use `Left` constructor, you need to know the type it constructs. And full type requires information on both `a` and `b`.

Better way to achieve polymorphism in Haskell is to use type classes. You can easily provide different implementations of "methods" for different instances.

Good comparison of both object-orientation and type classes concepts can be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OOP_vs_type_classes).

Answer (score 5):

You can make this work by explicitly specifying the other type:

```
main = do
  someFunc (Left "Test1" :: Either String ())
  someFunc (Right "Test2" :: Either () String)
```

but I agree with x13n that this probably isn't the best way to do whatever you're trying to do. Note that `someFunc` is functionally identical to

```
someFunc :: (Show a) => Bool -> a -> IO ()
someFunc False x = print $ "Left " ++ show x
someFunc True x = print $ "Right " ++ show x
```

because the only information you derive from the structure of the `Either` is whether it's a `Left` or `Right`. This version also doesn't require you to specify a placeholder type when you use it.

Comment: Per the question, the intent of the use of `Either` was to get a form of **polymorphism**.  The boolean-tag alternative you're providing doesn't do that.  The choice between `Left` and `Right` is also supposed to choose between two types.

Comment: @sacundim: Well, the call-patterns of my `someFunc` are identical to the `someFunc` in the question. Regardless of what the intent was, my definition *is* what was achieved; if what that is isn't what's desired, then that points to a problem in the original solution too :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question, because it made me think about *why* Haskell behaves this way.

```
class PseudoArbitrary a where
  arb :: a

instance PseudoArbitrary Int where
  arb = 4

instance PseudoArbitrary Char where
  arb = 'd'

instance PseudoArbitrary Bool where
  arb = True

reallyDumbFunc :: (PseudoArbitrary a, PseudoArbitrary b) =>
                  Either a b -> Either a b
reallyDumbFunc (Left x) = Right arb
reallyDumbFunc (Right x) = Left arb
```

So check this out. I've made a typeclass `PseudoArbitrary`, where instances of the typeclass provide a (pseudo-)arbitrary element of their type. Now I have a `reallyDumbFunc`tion that takes an `Either a b`, where both `a` and `b` have `PseudoArbitrary` instances, and if a `Left` was put in, I produce a `Right`, with a (pseudo-)arbitrary value of type `b` in it, and vice versa. So now let's play in ghci:

```
ghci> reallyDumbFunc (Left 'z')
Ambiguous type variable blah blah blah
ghci> reallyDumbFunc (Left 'z' :: Either Char Char)
Right 'd'
ghci> reallyDumbFunc (Left 'z' :: Either Char Int)
Right 4
```

Whoa! Even though all I changed was the *type* of the input, it totally changed the type and value of the output! This is why Haskell cannot resolve the ambiguity by itself: because that would require analyzing your function in complicated ways to make sure you are not doing things like `reallyDumbFunc`.